Can I use std::align to verify the alignment of a given pointer?
The following function template tries to locate an object in an array of bytes.
We may assume that the argument buffer "usually" holds an object of the given type, but I need a diagnostic (assertion check) against possible errors.
template <typename T>
T* get_object_from_buffer(std::uint8_t* buffer, std::size_t size)
{
    // EDIT: This constraint was missing in original version of the question.
    if (size != sizeof(T))
    {
        // Invalid usage of the function.
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    void* tmp_buffer = buffer;
    if (nullptr != std::align( alignof(T),
                               sizeof(T),
                               tmp_buffer,
                               size ) )
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        // Caller can check returned pointer to implement diagnostic reactions
        return nullptr;
    }
}

Questions:

Is it allowed (and portable) to do this using std::align?

Do you see a better solution - more robust, more elegant?


Conditions:

The function will be used on an embedded system.
Hence, some google hits for std::align usage on PC platforms are not applicable.

Buffer is filled by a function like the following:
    template <typename T>
    std::pair<std::uint8_t*, std::size_t> put_object_into_buffer(T* object)
    {
        return std::pair<std::uint8_t*, std::size_t>(
                        reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(object),
                        sizeof(object)
                    );
    }

Between the put/get functions, I have to pass the buffer through a library that is not
aware of user-defined types like T.



Edit/Update: The buffer representation of uint8_t* and size_t is only meant to hold a single T object. This was missing in the original question post.
I have added the check that the size argument actually matches the size of the object.
Without this check, std::align() can easily locate an aligned T* in buffer so that the criterion is not relevant any more.
Thanks to Ted Lyngmo for pointing this out!

What does "portable" mean in this context? Ts alignment requirement may be different on different platforms.

The function name, get_object_from_buffer, is a bit misleading since you return the same pointer you supplied to the function and not the aligned pointer.  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer) will break the alignment if tmp_buffer != buffer after std::align.

@TedLyngmo 1 - With "portable" I mean that the code is correct on "any" compatible platform (C++14). That is, I would like to treat the templated types in a way that it is evaluated correctly on any platform, including its (changing) alignment requirement.

@TedLyngmo 2a - I agree on the identifier, good point! When I prepared the minimal example for this question, I didn't think long about it.

@TedLyngmo 2b - I don't expect tmp_buffer != buffer - is this possible when casting from uint8_t* to void*? I think that pointer changes can only happen if the alignment requirement value rises, and that this cannot happen if we cast to void*.

The code is syntactically correct but it will cause an alignment violation in return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer) if buffer isn't already aligned for T. If the purpose is to find the first possible T in buffer, you should return tmp_buffer. You are casting to T* not void*. Returning buffer could lead to this. If you change that to return reinterpret_cast<T*>(tmp_buffer); there is no alignment issue. Perhaps you should verify that tmp_buffer == buffer if you expect buffer to actually be aligned?

@TedLyngmo You are right, there is something important I forgot in my sample code: I am expecting size == sizeof(T) - but well, I didn't write it...! Adding a check against this condition should fix the case you mentioned because std::align() cannot place a complete T in buffer if a buffer of sizeof(T) is misaligned. --> Updating the question...

In that case return reinterpret_cast<T*>(size == sizeof(T) ? std::align(alignof(T), sizeof(T), tmp_buffer, size) : nullptr); should do if I read it correctly.

... or in your updated question, after if (size != sizeof(T)) return nullptr; you don't need more ifs. Just: void* tmp_buffer = buffer; return reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::align(alignof(T), sizeof(T), tmp_buffer, size));

Both suggestions look corect to me. Are you working out an "answer" from it, or would you like me to do this?

I'm happy with you doing it. My lunch break is about to end :-)

Answer motivated by comments of @Ted Lyngmo - see comments to question

The check against size == sizeof(T) is essential.
Otherwise, std::align() will not return nullptr
whenever the size beyond a misaligned buffer pointer
allows to place an entire, aligned T instance
somewhere between &(buffer[0]) and &(buffer[size-1]).

Using the nullptr function return value for error cases,
it is not necessary to distinguish between buffer and tmp_buffer
if the return value is a type cast of std::align().
Then, the function can be shortened:
template <typename T>
T* get_object_from_buffer(std::uint8_t* buffer, std::size_t size)
{
    if (size != sizeof(T))
    {
        // Invalid usage of the function.
        // Caller shall check returned pointer to implement diagnostic reactions
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        void* tmp_buffer = buffer;
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::align(alignof(T), sizeof(T), tmp_buffer, size));
    }
}

or even
 template <typename T>
 T* get_object_from_buffer(std::uint8_t* buffer, std::size_t size)
 {
     void* tmp_buffer = buffer;

     // Caller shall check returned pointer against 'nullptr' to implement diagnostic reactions
     return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
             size == sizeof(T)
                 ? std::align(alignof(T), sizeof(T), tmp_buffer, size) 
                 : nullptr);
 }



